# substitute parameters into statement

Tags: python, postgresql

I am reading a huge log file around 50gb in size. It is a bunch of queries and parameters.

I have done the necessary cleanup and now the log look likes bunch of

```
select this_.x as x, this_.y as y, this_.ACTION_ID as ACTION3_291_0_ from table where this_.id=$1 and this_.type=$2 and this_.id=$3
$1 = '4', $2 = 'cleanup', $3 = '2323'
```

SO for each query(select here) there are parameters that i want to substitute.($1,$2,$3)

so the final query would be

```
select this_.x as x, this_.y as y, this_.ACTION_ID as ACTION3_291_0_ from table where this_.id='4' and this_.type='cleanup' and this_.id='2323'
```

How to do this in python. I am thinking of creating an ordered dictionary from the parameters (line2). Then read each word in line 1 and if value exists for key(word) in dictionary substitute.

Definitely there must be an easier way than this. Looking for thoughts.

Comment: `"Hello {}".format(some_variable)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary with a list of mappings, where the key is the value you want to search for and replace and the value is what you want the found key to be replaced with:

```
s = 'select this_.x as x, this_.y as y, this_.ACTION_ID as ACTION3_291_0_ from table where this_.id=$1 and this_.type=$2 and this_.id=$3'

mappings = {
    '$1': '4',
    '$2': 'cleanup',
    '$3': '2323'
}

# Loop through the dictionary, replacing every found occurency of they key with the value
for k, v in mappings.items():
    s = s.replace(k, v)
```

`print(s)`
`>>> select this_.x as x, this_.y as y, this_.ACTION_ID as ACTION3_291_0_ from table where this_.id=4 and this_.type=cleanup and this_.id=2323`